# Who is the person to speak to first when one wanted to be engaged to someone

Tags: quran, hadith, nikah, thinking

Assalamualaikum waramatullahi wabarakatuhu

I want to ask of the rule of getting engaged with someone, that should that person speak to the girl first or her parents or his parents and if is that girl in which manner should he speak to her, Bec many people said it is Haram to have a conversation with a female that you are not related to

Wa Salam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wa alaikum Salam waramatullahi wabarakatuhu

Please I want to make it very clear that whatever I say is base on my opinion

If it about been engaged, naturally you must have meet the girl or the boy somewhere before having interest in him/her, so after being interested the best thing to do is to tell your parents first because you must have an open relationship with them, just tell them mum,dad am interested in that man or that woman and as I responsible parents they will do absolute good job by inviting that person that look my so or my daughter has interest in you what did you think about it and you may even meet in the present of your parents and if both of you are okay then Allhamdulillahi.

Even if is on WhatsApp or Facebook just tell him or her that look we are creating a chat group that I will include either my brother or my father, a really relationship that what to become marriage will not refused that

Please try your best, is all for your protection

Jazakumul llahu khayran

Comment: I don't see how this really answers the question. There are many references one could use, but you answer based on your own opinion have you considered to think whether the described practice/option goes ahead with the teaching of Islam?